# Ubuntu 10.10 restarting while booting up sometimes

Tags: ubuntu

I've been using 10.10 on my notebook for about a week, as it started to behave like this:
Sometimes, while booting (while the "Ubuntu"-picture is showing, the one with the 4 dots representing the progress bar ), it shows " ######.#### restarting system", where #'s are "random" numbers followed by a reboot. I thought it could have something to do with usb-devices (I thought I've read something like that somewhere), so I tried unplugging - which didn't improve anything.
Does anyone have a clue in which direction I should dig? Google is no big help for me here, because I'm kinda lacking good keywords.

Comment: Press `Shift` when the BIOS has finished initializing the keyboard and hold it down until the Grub menu appears. At the menu, edit the first “Ubuntu …” entry, edit the `linux` line to remove the words `quiet` and `splash`, and boot. This will show verbose error messages. Report the last few messages.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, typing escape during boot will give you something a lot more verbose. Try to catch what happens before the reboot. Alternatively, the system logs in /var/log/syslog, if you look for the time before the last reboot, should have some info.

Edit, wild guess: maybe you are dual-booting, the other OS tells the bios it is doing a reboot, no one clears that, ubuntu see the "reboot" flag, interprets it differently and reboots.

Comment: I read the syslog - and I can't find any difference between the failed systemboot and the ones before that. 'pulseaudio' and 'vpnagent' are being started, followed by the logs from the new boot (after the restart) - w/o any clue to errors or anything :/

Comment: I in fact have XP installed, so this really might be the cause - is there anything I could do about it?